# iOS: Advantages of using updateSearchResultsForSearchController over textDidChange delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Right now, I have a search controller that updates the tableview with new results when I type into the search bar. I was using the following delegate `- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController;` However, the problem with this delegate is it changes the results when it becomes first responder. So if I use an `UIAlertViewController` (which I do) it resign the search bar and when the alert disappears the search bar becomes first responder again. Long story short this updates the results again and messes up my view.

When I started using  `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` this seems to be working well and does exactly what I need it to since this delegate doesn't get trigger when it becomes first responder.

I am wondering if using  textDidChange over updateSearchResultsForSearchController  is a good idea for updating results? I see a lot of example that uses updateSearchResultsForSearchController.